# What assertion functions are there in "minitest/spec"?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm using the new "minitest/spec" module to write specs for my classes, but it appears to be very poorly documented. Here's an example:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

module MyModule
    describe MyClass do
        it "can create a database scheme in memory" do
            test = MyClass.new(':memory:')
            test.create_database_scheme()
            test.table_names.must_equal ['foo', 'bar']
        end
    end
end
```

Here I'm utilizing the only spec-style assertion method I know: "must_equal". A logical variant that I tried, "must_be_true", didn't work. What assertion functions do I have to choose from?

Comment: I don't think "the information exists somewhere else on the internet" is a valid reason for down voting a question. After all, the information is *not* in Ruby's official documentation or on StackOverflow. If you down voted for some other reason, *please specify*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a simple Google search: http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html

To summarize:

- [must_be](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be)
- [must_be_empty](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be_empty)
- [must_be_instance_of](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be_instance_of)
- [must_be_kind_of](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be_kind_of)
- [must_be_nil](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be_nil)
- [must_be_same_as](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be_same_as)
- [must_be_silent](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be_silent)
- [must_be_within_delta](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be_within_delta)
- [must_be_within_epsilon](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_be_within_epsilon)
- [must_equal](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_equal)
- [must_include](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_include)
- [must_match](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_match)
- [must_output](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_output)
- [must_raise](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_raise)
- [must_respond_to](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_respond_to)
- [must_send](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_send)
- [must_throw](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_throw)
- [wont_be](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be)
- [wont_be_close_to](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be_close_to)
- [wont_be_empty](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be_empty)
- [wont_be_instance_of](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be_instance_of)
- [wont_be_kind_of](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be_kind_of)
- [wont_be_nil](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be_nil)
- [wont_be_same_as](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be_same_as)
- [wont_be_within_delta](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be_within_delta)
- [wont_be_within_epsilon](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_be_within_epsilon)
- [wont_equal](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_equal)
- [wont_include](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_include)
- [wont_match](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_match)
- [wont_respond_to](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-wont_respond_to)